# Reading pdf in win 8

Tags: windows-8

I need to read and edit existing pdf in win 8 app.
Editing pdf include adding text and images at any position on pdf.
Shall i go for xaml or javascript based coding.
which link should i follow that will give info for editing pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you : ....
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d115b1a4-bbcd-415d-81c4-fc167bf918f6/

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a beast of a file format. If you don't have lots of software development experience (which your question suggests you do not), writing a PDF editor from the ground up (especially if you have no team) can be a daunting task, even only considering the non-UI aspects of it.

Even should you implement a library that's 100% conforming to standards, you'll have to deal with all the faulty PDFs out there. Which very few readers, including the Win8 PDF reader, accomplish.

In case you're looking for a library, you should have a look at http://www.dynaforms.com/ - it can cope with most PDFs and has some editing functions and a renderer (in the professional version) as well and there's a Windows 8 compatible version of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ready framework, you can look at [Foxit Software](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/) solutions. They already have framework for Win8, but it can be expensive.